# Selecting Checkboxes in a table with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

So I'm trying to select the 4 swimming checkboxes on this page and then click next, using selenium with python:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo2ok.png

It has this html code:

```
<main class="scheduleVisitOnline container" role="main">
   <!-- See app.jsx for React component -->
   <div id="schedule-visit-wizard-app">
    <div class="chooseMembersStep">
     <h1 class="page-title">
      Schedule a Visit
     </h1>
     <p>
      <strong>
       Ann Arbor YMCA
      </strong>
      <br/>
      <a href="#">
       Change Branch
      </a>
     </p>
     <div class="chooseMembersStep__members">
      <label class="control-label">
       Select visiting members and any reservation-only areas you intend to utilize
      </label>
      <table class="chooseMembersStep__members-table">
       <tbody>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member">
         <td>
          <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
           <input checked="" id="member_3572218" type="checkbox"/>
           <div class="state p-success">
            <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
             <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z" style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
             </path>
            </svg>
            <label>
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td colspan="2">
          <label class="chooseMembersStep__member-name" for="member_3572218">
           Patrick McKeever
          </label>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
          <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
           <input id="3572218_39b9bf20-6493-4bd8-b2c4-6f6a4ab5a69d" type="checkbox"/>
           <div class="state p-success">
            <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
             <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z" style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
             </path>
            </svg>
            <label>
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
          <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_39b9bf20-6493-4bd8-b2c4-6f6a4ab5a69d">
           Hoops M-F / 7-8a /- 2 Half Courts (1 reservation per member family account)
          </label>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
          <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
           <input id="3572218_9a486991-672e-4a87-9130-05f379344968" type="checkbox"/>
           <div class="state p-success">
            <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
             <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z" style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
             </path>
            </svg>
            <label>
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
          <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_9a486991-672e-4a87-9130-05f379344968">
           Hoops M-S / 8a-8p /- 4 Half Courts (1 reservation per member family account)
          </label>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
          <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
           <input id="3572218_23d2d590-475d-44cd-84fd-c071bf299f89" type="checkbox"/>
           <div class="state p-success">
            <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
             <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z" style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
             </path>
            </svg>
            <label>
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
          <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_23d2d590-475d-44cd-84fd-c071bf299f89">
           Indoor Wellness Center
          </label>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
          <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
           <input id="3572218_b6470dcf-ab5d-44e5-85e2-4a50a1f7ffc7" type="checkbox"/>
           <div class="state p-success">
            <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
             <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z" style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
             </path>
            </svg>
            <label>
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
          <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_b6470dcf-ab5d-44e5-85e2-4a50a1f7ffc7">
           Lap Pool - Lane 1 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)
          </label>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
          <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
           <input id="3572218_34b69cbf-c890-4090-912e-1a2e32c805a9" type="checkbox"/>
           <div class="state p-success">
            <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
             <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z" style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
             </path>
            </svg>
            <label>
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
          <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_34b69cbf-c890-4090-912e-1a2e32c805a9">
           Lap Pool - Lane 2 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)
          </label>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
          <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
           <input id="3572218_7f453950-a5ba-424a-ac1e-a8c968519ab7" type="checkbox"/>
           <div class="state p-success">
            <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
             <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z" style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
             </path>
            </svg>
            <label>
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
          <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_7f453950-a5ba-424a-ac1e-a8c968519ab7">
           Lap Pool - Lane 3 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)
          </label>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
          <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
           <input id="3572218_28fed658-ad4e-4721-8b90-d6c943f0fac9" type="checkbox"/>
           <div class="state p-success">
            <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
             <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z" style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
             </path>
            </svg>
            <label>
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
          <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_28fed658-ad4e-4721-8b90-d6c943f0fac9">
           Lap Pool - Lane 4 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)
          </label>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
          <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
           <input id="3572218_c22ab33c-7850-4a52-a6e9-8737647ea54f" type="checkbox"/>
           <div class="state p-success">
            <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
             <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z" style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
             </path>
            </svg>
            <label>
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
          <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_c22ab33c-7850-4a52-a6e9-8737647ea54f">
           Lap Pool - Lane 5 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)
          </label>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
          <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
           <input id="3572218_24177575-8769-405b-af6a-5e5afdb10c56" type="checkbox"/>
           <div class="state p-success">
            <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
             <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z" style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
             </path>
            </svg>
            <label>
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
          <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_24177575-8769-405b-af6a-5e5afdb10c56">
           Lap Pool - Lane 6 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)
          </label>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
          <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
           <input id="3572218_0ee4cec1-2149-4af5-9c76-22abc6574d64" type="checkbox"/>
           <div class="state p-success">
            <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
             <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z" style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
             </path>
            </svg>
            <label>
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
          <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_0ee4cec1-2149-4af5-9c76-22abc6574d64">
           Showers (Reservation only necessary if you don't have a reservation in another area of the building)
          </label>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
         <td>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
          <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
           <input id="3572218_084dfd23-3ab5-4624-bcc8-bb7f8a25d30d" type="checkbox"/>
           <div class="state p-success">
            <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
             <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z" style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
             </path>
            </svg>
            <label>
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
          <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_084dfd23-3ab5-4624-bcc8-bb7f8a25d30d">
           Track
          </label>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-spacer">
         <td colspan="3">
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
     <div class="ctas">
      <button class="btn" type="button">
       Back
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
       Next
      </button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both;">
   </div>
  </main>
```

When I run the following lines of python though, the driver doesn't switch to the next page, indicating none of the checkboxes have been clicked (it won't allow you to switch pages if you don't click on at least 1 box.

```
wd.find_element_by_id("3572218_b6470dcf-ab5d-44e5-85e2-4a50a1f7ffc7").click()
wd.find_element_by_id("3572218_34b69cbf-c890-4090-912e-1a2e32c805a9").click()
wd.find_element_by_id("3572218_7f453950-a5ba-424a-ac1e-a8c968519ab7").click()
wd.find_element_by_id("3572218_28fed658-ad4e-4721-8b90-d6c943f0fac9").click()
wd.find_element_by_id("3572218_c22ab33c-7850-4a52-a6e9-8737647ea54f").click()
wd.find_element_by_id("3572218_24177575-8769-405b-af6a-5e5afdb10c56").click()

#actions = ActionChains(wd)

#actions.move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()

#wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="schedule-visit-wizard-app"]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]')

#time.sleep(1)

wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="schedule-visit-wizard-app"]/div/div[2]/button[2]').click()
```

The commented stuff was just me trying to see if actionchains could fix my problem.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[.//label[contains(.,'Lap Pool - Lane')]]")` will give you all 6 pool records. Now if you want to clicks on first 4 pool elements you need manipulate the list.

Now iterate over and click.

```
for chk in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[.//label[contains(.,'Lap Pool - Lane')]]")[:4]:
    chk.click()
```

You can use below code block as well

```
for chk in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[.//label[contains(.,'Lap Pool - Lane')]]")[:4]:
    chk.find_element_by_xpath("./preceding-sibling::td[1]//input").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe `find_element_by_xpath` helps you.

Try that:

```
wd.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'text on the list item you want to click')]").click()
```

You can replace the text with text like:
`Lap Pool - Lane 1 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)`